# using AutoMapper.IMappingOperationOptions in AutoMapper

Tags: automapper, projection

How to use the function AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(TSource source, Action opts) in AutoMapper ?

I think the 2nd param (Action opts) is there for declaring mapping options if needed but i can't find any API document for this function.

I would like to map 2 objects without having to creatmap first, if the 2 objects have exactly the same fields then the following command works: AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(TSource source)

Please help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you always have to use `CreateMap` first.

Comment: did you find a solution/answer?

Answer (score 2):

`Mapper.DynamicMap<Model, ModelDto>()` should do what you want.

I just tested it out and copied over the values from the source to the destination without requiring any `CreateMap` calls.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming across this older post, Automapper's docs have improved.
You can see examples of using the 2nd parameter for the Map function here:
https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Before-and-after-map-actions.html